# New Line \n or line break in authnet AIM x_description field for generated email

Tags: html, authorize.net

Is this possible?

I've tried newline, carriage return, and also just straight putting the `< br \>` into this field, and the email is just showing it all on one line none the less.

Comment: and yes i used proper <br /> context in actual code and \n\r

Comment: What did you end up using for this ?

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg Honestly, I don't remember, since it was 2011... But reading my comments in the answer, it appears that I might have had some errors in my line item syntax I was hitting the api with.  Might be worth taking a look at that.

Comment: I'll look into that. Also I'm using SIm rather than AIM, so maybe that makes a difference. I emailed their support about it, I'll post something here if I get a definite answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Their documentation doesn't say anything about valid characters or HTML being valid or invalid for that field. But if you cannot get it to work then that pretty much shows that you cannot do it.

Comment: well i mean if neither the newline characters nor the html character works clearly they are implementing some kind of filter.  Just have to trick is i suppose.  perhaps a \\nn instead of \n so if it removes the internal one it forms another?  i'll try some stuff.

Comment: It turns out I just had an error in the line item syntax on my request.  THe line item part of the authnet api was exactly what i was looking for when teamed up with the autoemailer from their server.